# how to make default value for @HTMLdropdownlistfor in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, default, html.dropdownlistfor

Iam passing a viewbag to view as a selectlist as below

```
    ViewBag.Currency = new SelectList(db.portal_lookup.Where(c => c.lookup_type 
== "FND_CURRENCY").OrderBy(m => m.lookup_description), "lookup_id", "lookup_description");
```

in view i show it as below

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.currency_code,
(SelectList)@ViewBag.Currency,"",new {  @class = "m-wrap" })
```

by default the value of this dropdownlistfor should be "IND" how can i set that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to fill up the model that you pass to the view, assuming that you're passing one, whereby you set

```
model.currency_code = "IND".
```

Alternatively, you could use the overload for new SelectList that allows you to specify the selected value:

> SelectList Constructor (IEnumerable, String, String, Object)
>   Initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the specified items for the list, the data value field, the data text field, and a selected value.

```
ViewBag.Currency = new SelectList(db.portal_lookup.Where(c => c.lookup_type == "FND_CURRENCY").OrderBy(m => m.lookup_description), "lookup_id", "lookup_description", "IND");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The first option is correct. The 2nd is wrong and does nothing at all when your binding to s model property (its ignored because the method internally builds its own select list based on the value of the property)